# how to set up an horizantal Partiting Distributed database Enviroment between two servers

Tags: oracle10g, distributed, distributed-system, distributed-database

suppose that i have a database for employees and i want to distribute the queres on two different servers at differnt location , let's say location a & location b .
I'm wondering how to distribute a table into two servers interconnected by network connection using oracle

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle Real Application Clusters (RAC)](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/real-application-clusters/overview/index.html) is the typical solution to clustering Oracle databases.

But RAC is usually a waste of time and money.  Let's be honest with ourselves and admit:

1. Very few databases need 5 9s uptime.
2. Very few databases need to access hundreds of petabytes of data.
3. Very few organizations have the time or money to hire and train people to administer distributed databases.  Without spending sufficient effort on administration, the extra complexity of a distributed solution may backfire and make the systems slower and less available.

A single-node, plain old database, is almost always good enough.